# Java Eclipse apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to read `MS Visio XML` (.vdx) files, by using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), but I am getting the exception below. I am using Java code in Eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.POIDocument.<init>(Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DirectoryNode;)V
    at org.apache.poi.hdgf.HDGFDiagram.<init>(HDGFDiagram.java:73)
    at org.apache.poi.hdgf.HDGFDiagram.<init>(HDGFDiagram.java:60)
    at org.apache.poi.hdgf.dev.VSDDumper.main(VSDDumper.java:48)
```

Is there any other library for reading visio file or visio xml file. or how could we convert MS visio xml into simplified `xml` or UML format.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

http://poi.apache.org/hdgf/index.html

Answer (score 0):

That exception means you have multiple copies of Apache POI on your classpath, of different versions.

You should ensure you have only one copy of the Apache POI jars (ideally the latest version, currently 3.8 Final)

If you're not able to work out yourself where the duplicate older POI jar is coming from, then the [POI FAQ on this topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) has some handy code you can use to identify where the duplicate jar is.

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI is an attempt to decode binary .vsd files, not the XML .vdx. The class name where your main is invoked does give you a hint.